# How to transfer Material Assignment data onto another mesh with same UV map and vertices

Tags: materials

I'm trying to transfer the Material assignment of a material set from the original mesh to a new rigged mesh that has the same UV map and vertices count, but the problem is when I make-link for materials, the material assignment doesn't follow and when I tried to make link for Object data, due to those 2 rigs have different size and causes the object that gets data being messed up.

Answer (score 1):

I have serched the way longtime. (I gave up it though) then requested it.
Would not You request it in blender right-click-select?

https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/rm5k/

I made script, it seems work now for me... I hope blender add same function as default

```
import bpy
tmode = bpy.context.active_object.mode
objs = bpy.context.selected_objects
so = bpy.context.active_object
to = None

if objs[0] == so:
    to = objs[1]
else:
    to = objs[0]

sms = so.material_slots

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = to

while len(to.material_slots) != 0:
    bpy.ops.object.material_slot_remove()

while len(to.material_slots) != len(so.material_slots):
    bpy.ops.object.material_slot_add()

i = 0    
while i < len(to.material_slots):
    to.material_slots[i].material = sms[i].material
    i += 1

tplgs = to.data.polygons
splgs = so.data.polygons

j = 0
while j < len(tplgs):
    tplgs[j].material_index = splgs[j].material_index
    j +=1
```

> > > > 

I changed script as add on. so you can transfer material slot assignment, materials, with UV (it auto transfer UV and activate  render UV) by one click.

just download and unzip, then install wifmatconvert_temp.py  as same as other add-on. ("Material", "Testing" group)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-0crLNntxFJOjNh3BTf4INxF21tx_f7q/view?usp=sharing

Usage

1. Select Source
2. Select Target (activate)
3. In Material property > Material link type > Click "Transfer Material".

you may need not use other functions. (Change object/data etc)

[image]
[image]

This add on auto generate and re-assign material-slots for target polygons as same as source , then transfer source materials , with transfer UV.

if you activate "Duplicate with suffix", it duplicate source materials and rename by your input suffix,  then add it for target / or simply link source material. (about both case, source material never change)

if someone test, edit, customize ,please use it as you need. I only test with 3.2

Of course until transfer mat-slots, you may better to duplicate your target mesh obj and keep it. (so you can easy return as dafault = transfer again)